# Формула DAX для ранжирования не работает

Tags: powerbi

Есть такая таблица TT:
Первый столбец t(имя, несколько раз может встречаться одно и то же),второй -Mark (оценка). В последний столбец  R нужно ранжировать t по сумме Mark. Пробую так,но не получается:

```
    RANKX(ALL(‘TT‘[t]),
CALCULATE(‘TT‘[Mark]),
ALLEXCEPT(‘TT‘,‘TT‘[t])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас пропущена последняя закрывающая скобка. И после CALCULATE нужно так: CALCULATE(SUM('TT' и т.д., дальше всё правильно.

Comment: Точно,  SUM пропустила! А я-то бьюсь уже час… Спасибо!